# E-R Schema in second normal form

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship, normalization, database-normalization

I have a doubt on a table in my E-R schema and the second normal form.
The table has an attribute that depends on another one and I don't know if 
this causes problems with the normalization.

The table structure is like this:

```
| contract_id | start_date | end_date |
```

The primary key is *contract_id*.
The problem is that the value of *end_date* is exactly 1 year after the *start_date*.

Rows example:

```
| 1 | 2013-01-01 | 2014-01-01 |
| 2 | 2012-02-03 | 2013-02-03 |
```

Is this table in 2NF?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it shouldn't be 2NF.
For 2NF to hold, there should not be a partial dependency on any column in a compound/composite primary key (which is not the case here).

Your question is more likely a concern for 3NF.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Yes, I know that it can be a 3NF problem but I had doubts about 2NF too. So, what about the 3NF?

Answer (score 0):

It is not covered by 2NF or 3NF but this model violates Domain/Key normal form. Simply remove one of attributes if interval is always is a year or add a check constraint.
e.g. CHECK (end_date - start_date = 365), 365 is financial year, calendar year is not a constant.

Comment: Yes, the interval is always a year and there is a trigger that check it. It is a business rule so it can changes and there is a chance that such rule is deleted. This is the reason why I left both attributes.

Comment: I think view is better to calculate end_date from start_date but it makes sense to store intervals for other constraints.

Answer (score 0):

A calculated column from other columns in the same row violates [3-NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). Some would tell you to not store the calculated column in your database to comply with 3-NF and that is indeed valid for the ***current*** model. However, you have to assess whether this is valid for your business or not. Suppose in 3 months time, the business rules change and the end_date is no longer equal to the start_date+1 year, what will you do?

Comment: If the rule changes I will edit the trigger that checks it.
But if the rule is deleted and there is no more functional dependency i need the end_date attribute.

Comment: My point is that you should assess how adding a new column would impact your system availability, re-development cost, testing, etc.

Comment: In this case, I would add the column now (unless you see a real harm not already mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

It is arguably not 2NF (presumably `start_date` is unique), but it is not 3NF, because you could use the expression

```
adddate(start_date, interval 1 year)
```

Or better create a view with `end_date` being this expression.

You also must ask yourself about data integrity: what happens to your database if through same mistake your end date is *not* one year after the start date? If the end date is calculated, such a situation is not possible - you get data integrity built in.

If end date is a separate column, every insert and update of these columns should be checked for correctness, which is more work and potentially more bugs.

Lastly, each row will be smaller if end date is not stored, which will give a small performance gain, although the gain may be insignificant.

Comment: There are triggers that check the correctness of the data, and I know this means more work and bugs.
The point is: what to do if the rule is deleted and I need the end_date attribute?

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't violate 2NF but it does 3NF.  you don't need to store a coputational field in the database.  that being said you don't have all the information you need to compute the value in the database either.  I would drop the `end_date` as stated above, but i would add a `contract_term` field.  it would be easy to do now that they are all 1 year, or 12 months, or however you chose to compute it, as opposed to in the future when they may change.  then you will be able to compute the expiration date faithfully even if the business needs change, plus you are not storing a computed field.  also, since `contract_term` describes the entity you are not violating 2NF or 3NF.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If start_date->end_date and end_date->start_date then it follows that (start_date,end_date) is not a candidate key because that composite would not be a minimal superkey. Therefore 2NF is satisfied because no proper subset of any candidate key is a determinant.

3NF means that for every dependency you require to be satisfied either the determinant is a superkey or the dependent attributes are part of a candidate key. The relevant question therefore is whether start_date and end_date are both candidate keys. If and only if they are then 3NF is satisfied. If start_date and end_date are nonprime (not candidate keys) then your table satisfies 2NF but not 3NF.